# Passing 156 character string to multiple functions

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a c# winforms .net 4 application which receives a 156 character message I then pass this message unchanged to multiple function in turn.

My question is is it inefficient to keep passing the same value as a parameter or is there a more efficient way?

so currently I have :

```
string code = getTheCode();
\\decode first part
string result1 = getResult1(code);
string result2 = getResult2(code);
...
```

value of code never changes after its initial assignment.

Comment: Strings are immutable so they never change anyway. They are reference classes too, so there is no copying involved when you use the same variable as a parameter multiple times. Finally, 156 characters is a *small* string

Comment: Strings are not copied, so this is as efficient as it gets. You are essentially passing a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  It is not inefficient to keep passing the same string as a parameter.  You are just passing a reference to the string, so it is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class with a constructor requiring you to pass your string as argument and set it as a private property. Then you could retrieve data using methods which would use this private property to calculate results.

But this is only a matter of coding style you prefer, of course (and whether you will use these methods in one or more places). For me it's more readable AND you get to make sure that code variable won't change in that instance of ResultGetter class.

```
public class ResultGetter
{
    private readonly string _code;

    public ResultGetter(string code)
    {
        _code = code;
    }

    public string GetResult1()
    {
        var returnValue = // do something with _code property    
        return returnValue; 
    }

    public string GetResult2()
    {
        var returnValue = // do something with _code property
        return returnValue;
    }

    // et cetera ad nauseam
}
```

And then in your main file:

```
var code = getTheCode();
var rg = new ResultGetter(code);
string result1 = rg.GetResult1();
string result2 = rg.GetResult2();
```

Comment: How is this going to be any different than the original, apart from being more verbose? Field access or parameter access, it's the same. Strings are reference classes. The only thing passed around is a pointer. By adding another class on top of the string though, you have *two* objects to GC instead of one

Comment: Way I see it, more verbose is more readable and it's matter of coding preference. It's certainly an alternative to OP's method and one I'd prefer. It's hardly more efficient than what OP uses.

Answer (score -1):

It may be inefficient to keep passing the same code to several methods. If you find you have to do this many times, you might want to create a class responsible for 'getting results'. Pass the ''code' in the constructor of this new class. This way you can reuse the 'code' during the lifetime of the class and you don't have to keep passing the same value as a parameter

Comment: `code` is a *string*.  Why is it inefficient to use the same string value in multiple function calls? And how would introducing *another* class on top of the string help?

Comment: I'm saying if you have many methods that require the same string as an argument, you probably want a class that is responsible for getting results. Of course you can pass a string to several functions. Passing the same string to many functions however, sounds like you are creating a class with too many responsibilities.